# Is it possible to change the bytecode a factory is using to create child contracts?

Tags: solidity, factory, template

Normally a factory includes the bytecode of any contract it creates. Now let's think about a scenario where there is an update of the child contract code necessary. I don't want to change existing childs, but I want to inject different bytecode into the factory, so from now on it produces the new variant of the child contracts.

Sample code:

```
contract Factory {
  // ...
  function newChild() returns (address) {
    Child c = new Child();
    return c;
  }
  // ...
}

contract Child_v1 {
  // ...
  public getVersion() constant returns (uint) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

When compiling this the bytecode of Child_v1 will be embedded into the Factory contract. Now I want to change the factory so it produces childs of the type Child_v2:

```
contract Child_v2 {
  // ...
  public getVersion() constant returns (uint) {
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to change the embedded bytecode of Child_v1 in Factory? E.g. I could compile Child_v2 offline and inject the new bytecode into the factory, something like this:

```
contract Factory {
  // ...
  function newChild() returns (address){
    Child c = new Child(); // should use bytecode as provided below
    return c;
  }
  function setChildCode(bytes[] bytecode) {
    // Some magic that updates the bytecode used in newChild() above
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider to implement something like a strategy pattern? You'd just need to keep the same interface, but swap any implementation you need:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

    //interface
    contract Greetable {
        function Greetable() public {}
        function greet() constant public returns (bytes32);
    }

    //container contract
    contract GreeterContainer is Greetable {

    //handle to the actual imlementation
    Greetable greeter;

    function GreeterContainer(address greeter_address) public {
        greeter = Greetable(greeter_address);
    }

    //here you pass the address of the concrete implementation you need
    //you'll have to deploy it seperately and have its address
    function setGreeter(address _greeter_address) public {
        greeter = Greetable(_greeter_address);
    }

    //this is where the code is getting "injected" in some way
    function greet() constant public returns (bytes32) {
        return greeter.greet();
    }
}
```

here is the full example: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2c42d6137295611f3c7db65cc995f8ca